# How do I concatenate two IntStreams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to create a `List<String>` with the numerical values from 72-129 and 132-200. I thought about using an `IntStream` and mapping the values to strings and collecting to a list. I used this code:

```
List<String> strings72to200 = Stream
        .concat(Stream.of(IntStream.range(72, 129)), Stream.of(IntStream.range(132, 200)))
        .map(e -> String.valueOf(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, if I debug the actual values of `strings72to200`, I get this:

```
[java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head@56d13c31, java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head@5f9127c5]
```

I believe that the `Stream.concat()` as well as the `.map()` are causing this, as I do have a working piece of code like this:

```
List<String> strings50to59 = IntStream.range(50, 60).mapToObj(e -> String.valueOf(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this piece uses `.mapToObj()` instead of `.map()`.

So the question is, how can I create a list with these values (note the initial split) via streams (as this seems to be smoother than a loop)? Should I create the full list and remove the unwanted items afterwards (unfeasible on bigger gaps)?

Comment: The issue is that `Stream.of(IntStream...` results in a stream of streams.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're passing to `concat` two `Stream<IntStream>`, which won't work (you want a stream of integers). You need to give it two `Stream<Integer>`:

```
List<String> strings72to200 = Stream
        .concat(IntStream.range(72, 129).boxed(), 
                IntStream.range(132, 200).boxed())
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And just a side note, if you intend to include `129` and `200` in the streams, you should use `IntStream.rangeClosed` (end is exclusive)

Comment: It "will" work. It will just give you a stream of streams.

Comment: This one works. I now even see why I used `Stream.of(IntStream.range(72, 129))` as I didn't know about `.boxed()` and without it, `Stream.concat()` wouldn't compile

Comment: And why not simply use `IntStream.concat(IntStream.range(72, 129), IntStream.range(132, 200)) .mapToObj(String::valueOf) .collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Answer (score 3):

You might just be looking for `boxed` there to get a `Stream<Integer>` and then concatenate :

```
List<String> strings72to200 = Stream.concat(
            IntStream.range(72, 129).boxed(), // to convert to Stream<Integer>
            IntStream.range(132, 200).boxed())
        .map(String::valueOf) // replaced with method reference 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

***Edit***: If you were to just get an `IntStream` from the given inputs, you could have concatenated them as:

```
IntStream concatenated =  Stream.of(
        IntStream.range(72, 129),
        IntStream.range(132, 200))
    .flatMapToInt(Function.identity());
```

or simply

```
IntStream concatenated =  IntStream.concat(
        IntStream.range(72, 129),
        IntStream.range(132, 200));
```

Comment: Nice thinking outside the box, the solution with `flatMapToInt`. Still, I don’t get why nobody came to the conclusion to simply use `IntStream.concat`.

Comment: @Holger well, actually I did look into the `IntStream` class to see why `concat` was not implemented for it, but still missed to find it and then tried the other approach. Not detailed look through it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a `Stream` of `IntStream`s with `Stream.conact()` where you get a `Stream<IntStream>` instead of a `Stream<Integer>`. You can just use [`IntStream.concat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#concat-java.util.stream.IntStream-java.util.stream.IntStream-) so solve this:

```
List<String> result = IntStream.concat(IntStream.rangeClosed(72, 129), IntStream.rangeClosed(132, 200))
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You also should use [`IntStream.rangeClosed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#rangeClosed-int-int-) instead of [`IntStream.range()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) if you want `129` and `200` to be part of the result.